# Android Studio Multidex Failed : Unknown verification type [73] in stack map frame

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I used Multidex to slove 65535.I already applied Android Multidex guide. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html 
But execution failed for task ':Unknown verification type [73] in stack map frame'.
This class in an Android library and I cannot modify it.It`s jar may be proguard.
How can I solve this problem?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':XXXXX:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar] (Can't process class [XXXXX.class] (Unknown verification type [73] in stack map frame))

This is my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

```
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':Android_Libproject')
compile files('libs/ant-1.9.5.jar')
compile files('libs/ant-launcher-1.9.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
compile files('libs/htmllexer.jar')
...........
```

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try to use compile `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

And also try to extends your Application class from :

```
public class ApplicationWrapper extends MultiDexApplication
```

Comment: yes，I have done these，but also having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it most probably comes from Proguard (which always being run when you enable multi-dex).

It can happen if your third-party library has classes with corrupt StackMapTable attributes - see [similar issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/420/) in Proguard's bug tracker.

If this is actually the case - your best bet will be to ignore this error by manually patching Proguard's `proguard.classfile.ClassConstants#ATTR_StackMapTable` field with `"dummy"` value, like this:

```
public static final String ATTR_StackMapTable = "dummy";
```

Afterwards, you'll have to build Proguard library and tell Android build chain to use your patched version. See Greg Ennis's [detailed instructions here](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/use-a-custom-proguard-build-with-gradle).

Just out of curiosity,  can you share the library name/binary? Is it proprietary or open-source?